# Переопределение метода при вызове дочерних классов, Python

Tags: python, наследование, переопределение

Есть родительский класс, в котором прописан метод **str**.
Также есть дочерние классы.
Родительский класс инициализируется двумя параметрами (предположим a, b)
Дочерние классы добавляют свои параметры, помимо a, b.
Суть программы в выводе информации в виде "Название класса (параметры)"
(Соответственно для родительского класса вывод "Название(a, b)", для дочерних "Название класса (a, b, параметры)"
Важно, что параметры указываются в скобочках.
Как, не переопределяя в дочерних классах метод **str** сделать закрывающуюся скобочку так, чтобы родительский класс также правильно отображался?

Я пробовал в родительском классе определить вывод таким образом:

```
f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self.a}, {self.b}"
```

А в дочерних просто вызывал метод super и конкатенации строк добавлял параметры, а в конце прописывал ")"

```
    def __str__(self):
    new_string = super().__str__() # определяем вывод в родительском классе
    return new_string + f'{параметр}' + f', {параметр 1})'
```

Тогда в дочерних классах вывод отображался корректно, а в родительском не было закрывающей скобочки. Если в родительском классе скобку указать, то вывод был "Дочерний класс(a, b (параметры дочернего класса)" (Нужно: "Дочерний класс (a, b, параметры)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то в методе `__str__` можно вытащить из `self.__dir__()` названия свойств, которые будут именоваться как параметры. Они будут отличаться от других (стандартных) свойств и методов отсутствием префикса `__`.

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__()
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __str__(self):
        vars = ", ".join(p for p in self.__dir__() if not p.startswith('__'))
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__} ({vars})'


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        super().__init__(a, b)
        self.c = c
        self.d = d


print(str(Parent(1, 2)))
print(str(Child(1, 2, 3, 4)))
```

```
Parent (a, b)
Child (a, b, c, d)
```

Вариант 2 - с использованием модуля `inspect`

```
import inspect


class Parent():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super().__init__()
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.arguments = inspect.signature(self.__init__)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__} {self.arguments}'


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        super().__init__(a, b)
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        self.arguments = inspect.signature(self.__init__)


print(str(Parent(1, 2)))
print(str(Child(1, 2, 3, 4)))
```

```
Parent (a, b)
Child (a, b, c, d)
```